# DDD, CQRS, Event Sourcing, Aggregates, Related Aggregates, and persistence

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate, persistence, cqrs

I am just getting into DDD, CQRS and Event Sourcing and am having trouble with the concept of related aggregates and how much data can be shared between the two when publishing events that involve both.  My issue... I have a customer aggregate that has a collection of address aggregates and an event that is published when an address is added to the customer.  Both address and customer aggregates maintain relationships with phone numbers/sales people and contacts.

My understanding is I can only reference an aggregate from another aggregate by id.  Am I allowed to pass more data about the address than just the address aggregate id to the customer when the address is added as long as I only reference the address id from the customer aggregate?

I think that I need extra data so when I publish the event I can eventually persist that data/relationship to the read side into a customer addresses table.

Answer (score 2):

When you find yourself trying to access data that belongs to another aggregate, you should double check to make sure that your aggregate boundaries are aligned with your needs.

That said, it is reasonable to *copy* information from one aggregate to another.  For instance, in a shipping domain, we're probably going to copy a shipping address into each shipment, but we probably don't manage the lifetime of the shipping address within the shipment entity itself.

So we tend to pay attention to which entities hold the authoritative information, and which are using stale immutable copies.  See Pat Helland [Data on the Outside....](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/09/13/data-on-the-outside-versus-data-on-the-inside/)

Comment: Thanks for the response and the link.  In this case I believe that the addresses lifetime is managed by the customer but since the address manages its own contacts/phone numbers etc. I thought I should break it out into its own aggregate.   Regardless how do I relate the two when I persist it to SQL for the read models?  Is that a table for addresses, a table for customers and a lookup table between the two?  Could you give me an example how you would model it?

Comment: It helps to go back to basics. The read model and write model/domain model are two completely different things. Reads and or searches are done on your read model which is highly optimised for the task. But the write model is very basic. Find by id and list all events by id in order is about as much as you generally need (unless you use snapshots). So you wouldn't 'relate' one aggregate with another on the write side as this sounds like a relational datamodel.

Comment: @Codescribler I am not trying to relate the write models. Right now the events are first persisted to the event store, and then I publish another event to persist to the read side DB.  My problem is that once that data is persisted to the read side, how do I relate "Customers and Customer Addresses"?  It is my understanding that you cannot directly query the event store.